# Nunit testing issue

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit-2.5

Ok, I have an Nunit test class setup that runs though a method, lets all it CalcBalance(). Within CalcBalance() we have another method that will save things to a database. I do not want to deal with the database when testing this particular method, but when I run my tests the database method throws an exception and causes the test to fail because the databases isn't setup/mocked. Example:

```
CalcBalance()
{

//Stuff I want to test

DatabaseInteraction()     //Throws exception

 return;         //This is the value I want to have tested.

}
```

My question is, is there any way I can set this up so that the Nunit tester will continue to test through even though the database interaction is saying it failed. I commented out DatabaseInteraction() and ran the test and it went through fine.

Comment: Something which may be worth bearing in mind in future is often the better the code sample, the better the answers. Here I have no idea if `DatabaseInteraction()` is a call to a static method, a local method or a delegate. Just a point to bear in mind :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functionality inside `DatabaseInteraction` which is causing the exception should be abstracted out to another class which implements an interface. This interface can then be mocked for use in unit testing.

For example:

```
public class BalanceCalculator
{
    readonly IDatabaseInteraction _databaseInteraction;

    public BalanceCalculator(IDatabaseInteraction databaseInteraction)
    {
        _databaseInteraction = databaseInteraction;
    }

    public Decimal CalcBalance()
    {
        //Stuff I want to test

        _databaseInteraction.Interaction();

        return 5.0D;         //This is the value I want to have tested.
    }
}
```

Then in the unit test, it can be done like this (using Moq):

```
[Test]
public void CheckValueTest()
{
    Mock<IDatabaseInteraction> mockInteraction = Mock<IDatabaseInteraction>();
    BalanceCalculator balanceCalculator = new BalanceCalculator(mockInteraction.Object);

    decimal result = balanceCalculator.CalcBalance();
    Assert.AreEqual(5.0D, result);
}
```

The `IDatabaseInteraction` is mocked to do nothing, so there is no chance of an exception or any unrelated functionality taking place.

For further information, read up on [Inversion of Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control), it is really useful for testability.

Comment: Would it be possible to just mock the current database interatction that I have already or would I have to put it in another class?

Comment: @Emerica. If you make it virtual; you can create a "partial mock" where you can mock certain methods but not others; though injecting it feels "cleaner" to me.

Comment: @Emerica. The current `DatabaseInteraction` you have looks like a method call, but if you do have some object which is performing some logic, you can mock that yes. The advantage of mocking interfaces though, is that you are not limited in what can be mocked. Mocking classes only works for non-sealed classes and only on properties and methods which are virtual. For an interface, everything on that interface can be mocked.

Comment: Ok, so the right way to go about it would be to put it in an alternate class then.

Comment: @Emerica. I would say so, it also results in much better Separation of Concerns, as your balance calculator won't contain any of the database logic.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you need to split up your code so each function/class has its own responsibility. After you split it up you can test each part separately.

Comment: Well it is the kind of thing that needs to save on the go. Changes need to be submitted in the event of a browser close or crash.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to agree with @Sebastiaan Megens here.  The 'correct' way to achieve this would be to

a) Have your database interaction loosely coupled using an interface and then simply create a mock DB in testing code or

b) Design your code so that each object can function as a standalone entity.

That being said, I believe you can configure your test to expect an exception of a certain type, meaning it wont fail if such an exception is thrown during execution.  Far from ideal but, this is the price you pay for tightly-coupled architectures.  On a similar line of thinking, in your test simply wrap the code which calls `MyObject.CalcBalance` in a try...catch and proceed as normal.